# Regex that match table input

Tags: regex

I have this kind of input
`||ID||Part Number||Product Name||Serial Number||Status||Dunning Status||Commitment End||Address||Country||
|1|SX0486|Mobilný Hlas Postpaid|0911193419|Active|Closed|04. 08. 2020|&nbsp;|&nbsp;|`

I am looking for two regexes, one that match only inside headers `||ID||Part Number||Product Name||Serial Number||Status||Dunning Status||Commitment End||Address||Country||` from whole table input so no match `|1|SX0486|Mobilný Hlas Postpaid|0911193419|Active|Closed|04. 08. 2020|&nbsp;|&nbsp;|` the other I could theoretically split by newlines and by |...

I have tried something like `[^\|\|]+(?=\|\|)` ist good solution?
[regex](https://regex101.com/r/LqGZX5/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can't negate a *sequence of characters* with a negated character class, only individual chars.

I suggest using a regex that will extract any chunks of chars other than `|` between double `||`:

```
(?<=\|\|)[^|]+(?=\|\|)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kIzJD2/1/).

**Details**

- `(?<=\|\|)` - two `|` chars must be present immediately on the left
- `[^|]+` - 1+ chars other than `|`
- `(?=\|\|)` - two `|` chars must be present immediately on the right.

If you ever need to make sure there is *exactly* two pipes on each side, and not match if there are three or more, you will need to precise the pattern as `(?<=(?<!\|)\|\|)[^|]+(?=\|\|(?!\|))`.

Comment: Can you help with the second part of spliting? I have tried naive split `split("\\|")` but left in array also |\r after last split and empty string before first match |. If it would be better use regex again.

Comment: @jirajira Following the logic I explained in my answer, you could try `(?<=\|)(?<!\|\|)[^|]+(?=\|(?!\|))`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/kIzJD2/2).